# How can I solve the trigonometric equation $\sin 3x- 2\cos^2x =0$?

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to express it by $\sin x$ and got this:

$$3\sin x -4\sin^3x+2\sin^2x-2=0$$

But this is not going to be factorised.

Comment: "but this is not going to be factorised" - what do you mean by this? You have obtained a cubic equation in the variable $t= \sin x$, now solve it

Comment: @YuriyS Presumably OP means that the cubic equation in $t$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, so there there is no nice expression for the real root of $t$.

Comment: You can feed it to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x-4x%5E3%2B2x%5E2-2%3D0) which presumably uses Cardano's formula.  It finds one real and to complex roots.